# How to retrieve the number of unassigned orders in ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.4, routing, vehicle-routing-problem

I'm using ArcPy for a vehicle routing problem in ArcGIS Desktop. I'm using the Network Analyst tool to find the minimum number of routes needed to service all orders given some constraints. I can create and solve the routing problem in AcrPy, but I can't figure out how to return the number of unassigned orders.

Some things I've tried:

```
temp = arcpy.na.Solve("Vehicle Routing Problem")
solution = temp.getOutput(0)

###Now check what it can do###
dir(solution)
```

'Solution' is a group layer. I had expected to see information about the routes, orders, etc. - but couldn't find any of it.

Then I thought that the information could be present in a different layer, so I checked a list of layers, but didn't find anything interesting:

```
document = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(document)
```

This matched by Table of Contents, but not the contents of the Network Analyst window (which is what I really wanted).

Eventually I gave up op on the idea that the information I wanted was attached to a layer. I found [this article](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/network-analyst/solve-vehicle-routing-problem-output.htm) on the ESRI website which references an "UnassignedOrders" table, but I have no idea how to access that.

Comment: Are you using ArcPy and Network Analyst with ArcGIS Desktop or ArcGIS Pro?  For coding questions it is always best to include a code snippet that illustrates what you have tried and where you are stuck to encourage potential answerers to test if they do not just know.

Comment: @PolyGeo - Thanks for the direction. I've edited to include that info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The help link you refer to is for ArcGIS Pro. You are working in ArcMap, so you should be looking at this help page: [Vehicle routing problem analysis](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/guide-books/extensions/network-analyst/vehicle-routing-problem.htm).

To iterate through the unassigned orders, you have to look into the `Status` field of the `Orders` layer:

After a solve operation, the status can be modified using one of the following status values:

> OK (0)—The network location was successfully evaluated.
>
> Element not traversable (3)—The network element that the network
>   location is on is not traversable. This can occur when the network
>   element is restricted by a restriction attribute.
>
> Invalid field values (4)—The field values of the network location fall
>   outside the analysis layer's coded or range domains. For example, a
>   negative number may exist where positive numbers are required.
>
> **Not reached (5)**—The network location can't be arrived at by the
>   solver.
>
> If time windows are used and the route arrives early or late, the
>   value changes to Time window violation (6).

Therefore run this code in your map document open with the VRP layer created and solved:

```
>>> mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument('current')

>>> orders = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, 'Orders')[0]
>>> orders
<map layer u'Orders'>

#to get all orders names and status
>>> [f for f in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(orders, 'Name Status'.split())]
[(u'Graphic Pick 1', 5), (u'Graphic Pick 2', 0), (u'Graphic Pick 3', 0), (u'Graphic Pick 4', 0), (u'Graphic Pick 5', 5), (u'Graphic Pick 7', 5)]

#to count only unassigned
>>> len([f for f in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(orders, 'Status') if f[0] == 5])
3
```